# Code Coverage for Static Library (as in Apple sample project)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, static-libraries, code-coverage

I've been trying to get code coverage stats for my static library that is written in Objective-C, which is set up the same way as the Calculator-iOS target in the Apple sample project - "Unit Testing Apps and Frameworks", which can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UnitTests/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011742

In this project, when code coverage is enabled on the Calculator-iOS target, which runs the Calculator-iOS_LogicTests tests, the finished result does not display any code coverage stats. Only when "test bundles enabled" is selected, can some test stats be seen, but this simply shows the Calculator-iOS_LogicTests bundle which includes BOTH the test classes AND the classes under test.

My own static library project behaves the same way - I do not see code coverage for the static library target, and can only see the test bundle code coverage (if selected) which simply shows a mix of test classes, and classes under test.

How can I view the code coverage stats for my static library target ONLY?

Thanks

Comment: Do we have any update on this one?

Comment: Did anyone find anything for this ?

Comment: Some news about it ?